# Friendly URL's .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I want to make a Friendly URL for my social network, i'm using phpDolphin script
that's a sample profile link `http://sample.com/index.php?a=profile&u=admin`
i want to make the profile URL to be like this `http://sample.com/admin`

my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$ index.php?a=$1&q=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That I got it but can you tell me for which user it didn't work?

Comment: All the users !! e.g.. http://frds.tk/leader3 this link for another user wich is not the Admin !! you will find that this link opened the Admin profile !! not leader3 profile

Comment: Ah there was a typo, please try it now.

Comment: Worked :D Thanks, if you have a FaceBook account,i want to add you :) Please. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. I'm not active on FB, but you can connect with me on LinkedIn:  `http://www.linkedin.com/in/anubhava`

Comment: I've added you ! or connected to you :D whatever